# Exporting Oracle 11G R2 dump file

Tags: oracle11gr2

I am new to oracle and need to start a project. For this I need to restore a dump file. I tried all the methods, but not getting success. Dump file is from Oracle 11 G R2 and same version is installed on my desktop Windows PC. Steps followed are as below:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\kartikeyap>SQLplus

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Sep 8 23:38:58 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: SYSTEM
Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> create tablespace csiprod datafile 'csiprod' size 3000M
  2  ;

Tablespace created.

SQL> create user csitest identified by csitest default tablespace csiprod temporary tablespace temp;

User created.

SQL> grant all privileges to csitest;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> create or replace directory c_drive as 'C:/';

Directory created.

SQL> grant read,write on directory c_drive to csitest;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

C:\Users\kartikeyap>cd\

C:\>impdp SYSTEM/diya2478 schemas=csitest directory=c_drive dumpfile=csiprod.dmp;
```

But every time I am getting error below:

```
Import: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Thu Sep 8 23:44:50 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
ORA-31640: unable to open dump file "C:/csiprod.dmp;" for read
ORA-27041: unable to open file
OSD-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: (OS 2) The system cannot find the file specified.
```

It will be of great help if someone take a look and get this resolved for me.

Comment: My dump file is residing in C:\ drive

Comment: First, I'm guessing that your file name does not actually have a semicolon at the end.  The error indicates that the file doesn't exist on the server machine.  Assuming the database server is running on your local machine and that you do have a file "c:\csiprod.dmp" then the immediate issue is that you've got an extra semicolon

Comment: Oh Great.... Now the error has been changed to...

Comment: C:\>impdp SYSTEM/diya2478 schemas=csitest directory=c_drive dumpfile=csiprod.dmp

Import: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Fri Sep 9 11:07:23 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39165: Schema CSITEST was not found.

Comment: sorry able to do it as schema was csiprod not csitest. Thanks @Justin Cave